# SQL Query to Grid from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, grid, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

I am trying to write a query to display to a data control.

I'm having some issues trying to get the query I need.

**I want the grid to to display:**

```
product name     dealer 1        dealer 2     dealer 3      dealer 4, etc  <br/>
product a        10              12            18           N/A  <br/>
product b        32              N/A           7            4  <br/>
product c        35              36            21           18  <br/>
```

**Database Tables:**

```
products 
id, name

dealers  
id, name

products_to_dealers_xref
product_id, dealer_id, qty
```

I can't figure out how to get the query to layout like this.
 I'm currently trying the UNION statement, but still can't get it.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pivot the results of the query using the [PIVOT Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
select Products.Name,'dealer 1','dealer 2','dealer 3','dealer 4'
from
( select Products.Name,qty from products inner join products_to_dealers_xref pd on Products.id = pd.product_id inner join dealers d on Products.Id = d.id) as p
Pivot 
(sum(qty) for products.name in (['dealer 1'],['dealer 2'],['dealer 3'],['dealer 4'])) as pvt
```

**P. S.:** not tested.

Comment: had to change some things around, but the pivot worked. thanks.